# Access network shared printer from wine command prompt

Tags: command-line, networking, wine, printing

I have connect a shared printer in my ubuntu desktop and I have installed wine 1.6. I ran a vb application in wine and I want to print the output txt file of the vb application.  Printer is shared in the ubuntu desktop. For that I need a command which can print the txt file from the wine command prompt.

Thanks you

Answer (score -1):

save the text file to your Ubuntu desktop, and print the file with lpr. Check this [page](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Printing-Usage-HOWTO-2.html), it might be of some use.

Comment: Couple points: 1) OP requested to print from wine's command line, `lpr` works from Ubuntu's command line.  Explain why or why not it can be achieved. 2)  While suggesting a command is good, it's always better to include an example of how command works. Sample output is always welcome too. In general, try to keep high quality of answers, pay attention to details. Weclome to the site  and keep on improving yourself !